# How do you import music into iTunes without creating duplicates of existing entries?

Tags: itunes, macos

Before importing the same directory (the exact same absolute path) that had already been imported into iTunes previously, containing mostly the exact same files (the exact same absolute path) as those already referenced by the iTunes library, I [researched the issue with ending up with duplicates in iTunes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5605328?answerId=23930274022#23930274022):

> You could drag a file from another drive to iTunes 100 times and iTunes will add a new copy of it each time giving you 100 duplicates.  It will only not do this if the copy on the other drive is the actual copy pointed to in the iTunes library. In other words that other drive is part of your library, not just a source of files.  **If the copy on the other drive is the copy iTunes points to then it will ignore it.**

I had a vague memory of iTunes not being able to do this properly a few years back, but since I couldn't think of a single reason why it would be useful to have large sets of duplicate references I accepted the idea that it had since been fixed.

Well, iTunes did not ignore the files already referenced. I now have duplicate references for almost every file reference in the library.

Here are the things I don't understand:

- How am I supposed to update the library to account for new files without ending up with thousands of duplicates?
- In what way are duplicates so useful that they're the default behavior?

To clarify, I'm not asking how to deduplicate a library, but how to import a root media directory without ending up with duplicate references to already referenced files.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is in your specific case and there's almost certainly an easier way (which is why I'm leaving it as a comment rather than an answer) but you could always write a script that combs through your iTunes media directory and the directory you want to import and compares md5 hashes of the files to find the dupes, then copies any files you don't already have to a separate directory you could then import from. Glancing at your network profile it looks like you have enough knowledge to either do that or figure out how.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the suggestion! I figured you had looked at my profile page. I don't think that method is for me though. It defeats the purpose of having a library if the application is incapable of properly managing it. Now that I've discovered that iTunes can't provide a way to select all but one of every duplicate even after offering to show me all duplicates, I'm very close to concluding that whoever designed this application had a blindfold on.

Comment: No argument from me on that. I will say though that pretty much no music player (and I've tried a **lot**) is all that great. Most of them anymore treat on-device files as an afterthought to cloud playlists.

Comment: @JaredSmith You're right about that. I just got tired of unreliable streaming and nonexistent buffering in Plex, and the UI of its ugly cousin Emby, and wanted to instead sync to phone from an organized library. I'll probably have to learn to live with duplicates :)